# How to detect Command-Shift-Click for OS X in javascript?

Tags: jquery, macos, backbone.js, pushstate

Normally, this combination opens a link as a new tab in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari for Macs. Is there any way to detect this? I know of jquery's `event.which`, but it gives a value of `1`, which is indistinguishable from a simple left click.

The use case is with Backbone HTML5 pushstate, where I want to attach a `'click'` event handler that does not trigger a page load for normal navigation, yet still allow users to open a link in a new tab with a ⌘-⇧-click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the event's `metaKey` and `shiftKey` properties:

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
  if(e.metaKey && e.shiftKey) {
    console.log("Command+Shift+Click");
  } else {
    console.log("Other click");
  }
});
```

so if, for instance, you are doing `#!` routing instead of actually following urls, and want command or command+shift to do normal behavior (open up in a new tab), you would have something like

```
function followLink(e) {
  if(!e.metaKey) e.preventDefault();
  yourApp.navigate('/link');
}
```

Comment: For pushState, to make this also work in windows you need to check e.ctrlKey. http://chrome.blogspot.com/2009/08/tip-opening-links-in-new-tabs.html